# How to color a value in a dataframe based on a condition and export it to a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like this one:

```
     Col 1      Col 2          Time 1
0     A          A_1          24:00:00
1     A          A_2          18:00:00
2     B          B_1          36:00:00
3     B          B_2          78:00:00
```

I want to make a condition in the "Time 1" Column and if it's `>72:00:00` fill it with red color. And then to export it to csv and have an output like this one:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hey @Tomerikoo, I saw that one and didn't solve my problem.

Comment: If you saw this one it means that you are aware of `style.apply` and if it didn't help you then it means you tried something that didn't work. In that case it is better to post a [mre] of your attempt so we can help with your problem. Simply saying I saw this one and it didn't help doesn't help us to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly create a function that check condition:

```
def highlight(s):
    res=s.str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)>72
    return ['background-color: red' if v else '' for v in res]
```

Finally use `style.apply()`:

```
df=df.style.apply(highlight,subset=['Time 1'])
```

Output of `df`:

[image]

Comment: Hey @anuragdabas, i tried your solution in my dataframe and it is working good if the values in "Time 1" column are <100. If i have a value there that is for example 150:00:00. it wont make it red. How can i solve this?

Comment: @user14073111 Updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**